# How can i make lines on the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have completed modelling the mesh and i want to make lines on the mesh. How can i make the net lines on the body. I do not want to have texture reason i want that lines to give some volume and make thickness. Any suggestion that i can make quick lines on the body. Thanks

**Below File with face and shrink wrap**
[image]

[image]

**with the reference image i have**
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: So do you want to actually add those details (in which can you could just model or sculpt them on) or have them painted on (in which case textures would be the way to go)?

Comment: Create a new mesh (just one vertex at the beginning), add a shrink wrap, set "snap to face/closest" and now extrude the vertex along the model, following the lines you want. Once done, you can convert to curve, for instance.

Comment: You can paint them and use bump map, paint them and use microdisplacement or use texture for both above. You can sculpt them, you can even snap Grease Pencil to the mesh and convert it to the curve. Choose one and you'll get answer quickly :)

Comment: @lemon as suggested above i have taking the single vertex and extruded and made the web i have attach the blend and image file its not getting the mesh good way on the face