# How to create and wrap a 3d web pattern on a Spider-Man model?

Tags: mesh, objects

So i have this spidey model that ive used sort of like a canvas to learn stuff. i just started learning blender not even a week ago and i got texturing done and making different mesh sculpts like the spidey emblem done but im having trouble with creating a 3d web pattern. How could i go about it? ive tried a couple different things like curve paths and a plane mesh and drawing on the model and converting the drawing to mesh and all have been a bit difficult to learn.

this is how it looks like just as it is right now.
[image]

and this is sort of the idea im looking for.
[image]

Help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: search this site for "shrinkwrap" and that might help with ideas

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76790/how-can-i-make-lines-on-the-mesh